# The semantics of until operator in linear temporal logic

Tags: modal-logic, kripke-models, linear-logic

According to the definition of until operator from Wiki:

> $w \models \varphi~\text{U}~\psi$ if there exists $i \geq 0$ such that $w^i \models \psi$ and for all $0 \leq k < i, w^k \models \varphi$.

If the first state $w^0$ is $\neg \varphi \wedge \psi$ or $\varphi \wedge \psi$, does we have $w \models \varphi~\text{U}~\psi$ ? It is the case $i = 0$ for above defintion, thus it should be true.  But i am not sure, because $\varphi \wedge \psi$ seems to not be proper with the semantics of until operator.

Comment: "φ Until ψ" reads "φ must remain true until ψ becomes true"

Comment: Not clear your last comment, but if $\psi$ is already true in state $w^0$, this means that there is no prior state $w^k$ where $\varphi$ is true: $0≤k<0, w^k \vDash \varphi$. Thus, the condition is vacuously true.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So the above two cases $w^0 = \neg \varphi \wedge \psi$ and $w^0 = \varphi \wedge \psi$ are both satisfying $w \models \phi \wedge \psi$?

Comment: @maplgebra in both cases $w \models \varphi \mathsf{U} \psi$ since $\psi$ is already true at point $0$

Comment: I suppose it been satisfied based on this definition.